# ActionScript 3 - sound mp3 is not played without error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Help me, I use Adobe Flash CS3 Professional.

```
// i have try using this import, but still not work
/*import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.media.Sound;
  import flash.net.URLRequest;
*/

// here is the code
var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("music.mp3");
var snd:Sound=new Sound();
snd.load(req);
var chan:SoundChannel=snd.play();// not work using 'snd.play(1);' too

chan.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete); 
function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event){
  trace("Musik Complete");
}
```

When i run the swf or `ctrl+enter`, the output `Musik Complete` without any sound played, but the animation still played. For the animation i just create simple twin motion.

i work on this directory

```
C:/flash/example.fla
C:/flash/example.swf
C:/flash/music.mp3
```

I have try to import `music.mp3` into the library too.

Note: I get the example from my friend(.swf, .fla, .mp3). I play the .swf that shared by my friend and work, but when i try to create by my self, is not work. So, i think `music.mp3` was fine to use for Flash. Here is my friend code:

```
var Audio:musik = new musik();
var chan:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
// play
chan=Audio.play();
// stop
chan.stop();
// i am so confuse i run my friend project and work fine (sound and other), if i write from scrap even i write the same code, there is an error, and this the error:
// 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: musik.
// 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method musik.
```

Comment: PS : `var chan:SoundChannel=snd.play();` will not work because you did not instantiate `chan` as a **new** variable of type _SoundChannel_. It should be : `var chan:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();` then you can follow that with `chan = snd.play();`

Comment: @VC.One Wrong, `play()` creates a new `SoundChannel` object.

Comment: @Vesper I expect `var snd:Sound=new Sound(); snd.play();` to work but can you explain why asker's code `var chan:SoundChannel=snd.play();` isn't working?

Comment: @VC.One He's getting an error at `snd.load(req)` with some sort of IOError thrown, most likely an attempt to load a data file without a web server. `play()` tries to stream an URL'd file if possible, MP3s are streamable, so you download a part of a file and can play that part before loading the entire file. Getting an error over there makes play() do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just watch on youtube, i missing one step.
In library, open properties of `music.mp3` and give it class name.

[image]

So, we can call the class using this `var Audio:musik=new musik();`.
Then, create the Sound Channel.
At least, function to play and stop using this:

```
//play
chan=Audio.play();
// stop
chan.stop();
```

Comment: You have just embedded your MP3 into your SWF instead of dynamically loading it after SWF starts. Works for small/er resources, does not for large/er ones and for a dynamic resource set. You'd better employ URL loading properly if you're targetting to change a something within loaded resources.